# How to Save Multiple Values in jQuery Autocomplete to MySQLi DB?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, mysqli

I'm just learning about the jQuery AutoComplete Widget. The values pop up with a comma nicely.  So, the visual display to the user is great.

My issue is how do I save the multiple values to a MySQLi database?

Here is the code:

```
     <script>
     $(function() {
      var availableskills = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
         ..........
         more languages
        "XML"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#skills" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            // could have source as a "url"
            source: function( request, response ) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableskills, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Now, here's my input id for letting the user select the skills:

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
<!--<label for="skills">Tag programming languages: </label>-->
<input type="text" id="skills" size="50" />
 </div>
```

Not sure on how to save the skills the user selects into a database.  I can save data to a MySQLi db with ease; the issue is how can I take say three skills and save them into three different rows in a table in a database.

Any help, very much appreciated.

Ken

Comment: Is your input inside a <form> tag? What is your server-side language and framework?

Comment: @keithjgrant, yes this is in a form tag.  Just neglected to include it to save people from reading it.  Sorry.  It would have added clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example you will do form post with the input name skills

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<div class="ui-widget">
<input type="text" id="skills" size="50" name='skills' />
</div>
</form>
```

then test.php would be something like

```
<?php
//...do some mysql connections
$skills = explode(",",$_POST['skills']);
foreach($skills as $skill){
    $statement.="INSERT INTO blahblahblah SET skill = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($skill);
}
$mysqli->multi_query($statement);
```

Comment: sorry.  I am using MySQLi and not MySQL.  If you don't mind, how would I adjust this for MySQLi?  Thanks.

Comment: it's now mysqli if you are using procedual style. oo-style would be $yourmysqliobj->multi_query(X)

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not that advanced.  I don't quite understand your adjustment recommendation.  Sorry.

Comment: show us your php code then we can figure out the exact modification then.

Comment: I have this:

$skills = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['skills']);
  foreach($skills as $skill){
   $statement.="insert into individual_skills SET Skills_Name = ".$skill.";";
  }
  mysqli_multi_query($statement);

My Errors are:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Warning: mysqli_multi_query() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Again, any help so much appreciated.  I can feel I'm so close.  Thanks.

Comment: Made little change.  Now just one WARNING:  

mysqli_multi_query() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: The change I made was returned the explode above the foreach loop and then put the realescape back where you had it originally.

Comment: simply change mysqli_multi_query to $mysqli->multi_query

Comment: Thanks.  Did not work.  I appreciate all your work.  Sorry to have bothered you.  Maybe next time . . .